# Unity Connect to azure Sql Database with AppServices

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine

So I want to connect to my Azure Sql Database using in a unity project,
I used this code provided in the readme of [app services Github project](https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/AppServices/blob/master/README.md):

```
    public class AzureConnect : MonoBehaviour {
    private MobileServiceClient _client;
    private MobileServiceTable<Score> _table;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _client = new MobileServiceClient("https://myService.azurewebsites.net"); // <- add your app url here.
        _table = _client.GetTable<Score>("Score");
        ReadItems();
    }
    private void ReadItems()
    {
        StartCoroutine(_table.Read<Score>(OnReadItemsCompleted));
    }

    private void OnReadItemsCompleted(IRestResponse<Score[]> response)
    {
        if (!response.IsError)
        {
            Debug.Log("OnReadCompleted: " + response.Url + " data: " + response.Content);//content shows the content of the table properly
            Score[] items = response.Data;//Data is always null
            Debug.Log("Todo items count: " + items.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Read Error Status:" + response.StatusCode + " Url: " + response.Url);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly and connects to my DB just fine but for some reason the response DATA is always null although the response CONTENT returns a string with the data in the scores table just fine Any Idea what could be the problem?

PS: the url of the App service is not the real one I use just for demo purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've been struggling with this for hours , and after 6 min of posting the question I figure out the answer so here is the Answer so anyone that faces this problem can know the cause:

The Problem was that I didn't declare my Score Class as [Serializable] as soon as I declared it this way it worked perfectly.